Find $K_r$-subdivisions in random graphs
I saw the following exercise in Shapira's note, page 22-23.
Prove that with high probability, $G(n,1/2)$ does not contain a $K_t$-subdivision (also called topological minor) with $t=10\sqrt n$, but does contain a $K_t$-subdivision with $t=\sqrt n /10$.
I can only prove the former part of the exercise, but I failed to prove the latter part. I wonder if someone could help me with this, i.e.
Prove that with high probability, $G(n,1/2)$  does contain a $K_t$-subdivision with $t=\sqrt n /10$.
[proof of the former part]. If every vertex set $T$ of size $t$  induces $\le \binom{t}{2}-n$ edges in $G(n,1/2)$, then it does not contain a $K_t$-subdivision.
For a fixed vertex set $T$ with $|T|=t$, \begin{align*}&\mathbb P\left(e(T)\ge \binom{t}{2}-n\right)\\
&=\mathbb P\left(e(T)-\frac{1}{2}\binom{t}{2}\ge \frac{1}{2}\binom{t}{2}-n\right)\\
&\le
\mathbb P\left(e(T)-\frac{1}{2}\binom{t}{2}\ge 19n \right)\text{, Chernoff bound}\\
 &\le 
 2e^{-2\frac{(19n)^2}{\binom{t}{2}}}\le e^{-n}.\end{align*}
So, the probability that every vertex set $T$ of size $t$  induces $\le \binom{t}{2}-n$ edges in $G(n,1/2)$ is at least
$$1-\binom{n}{t}e^{-n}=1-o(1).$$

Maybe the following idea works:
Choose any subset $S$ of $t$ vertices. Between each pair of vertices of $S$, try and find vertex disjoint paths of length 2. $\binom t2$ is only about $n/200$. But every pair of vertices has about $n/4$ common neighbors. So you can go through the pairs one at a time and select a path of length 2 connecting them (you only need to if there isn't already an edge between them, but who cares). Use Chernoff to make the $n/4$ common neighbors statement formal.
